# Relational Database to Triple Store

Tags: java, mysql, triplestore, triples

I am trying to write a java program to transform the information from a MySQL table into triples, so I can later import them into a triple store. Is it possible to do so without creating an auxilliary  `RDF/XML` file? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of different interfaces for interacting with triples in Java. You have Jena, Sesame, and OWLApi. Jena has an in-memory store for triples. It can output to several different notations, including RDF/XML but also N3, binary format, SQL database...

I think these APIs also allow you to directly connect to a triple store using standard protocols.

See http://www.scribd.com/doc/32983777/An-open-portable-AST-for-software-engineering-tools#outer_page_46 for more information, I have written a small part about this in my thesis :-)

Comment: I want to transform SQL to RDF, so I need to connect to a SQL database and CREATE triples.

Comment: Your goal is to convert a SQL database to a triple-based data format, and then to import it in some other system. The answer to your question is: "You have a wide choice of formats to save your intermediary result, including storing in memory or in a SQL db". Why not save it into the final system directly?

Comment: Now I understand what you meant, and I have also found a solution, using the Jenna API. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Python script :dbview.py provides a mapping from a mySQL, producing linked virtual RDF data files.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/ConverterToRdf

Never did it directly